# How can I get the chats from Whatsapp Business in specific time range using Python and Whatsapp API

Tags: python, data-science, whatsapp, analysis

I want to get the chats that my customer wants me to analyze and I need to write a code that export chats to CSV using Python and Whatsapp API.

I tried using Selenium but its not available for me to use in company so I need to use Whatsapp Business API to get chats in last30days for example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.